# Catastrophic Failure - Out of Memory when opening a User Form

Tags: excel, vba, out-of-memory

I have a VBA program that opens a series of userforms.
I designed the entire thing on my laptop, and tested it on some other laptops.  Both in Excel 2010 and 2016.

I shared it with coworkers who use a different style of laptop (Win7, Office 2010).  Every time they hit the button to open the userform they get a Catastrophic Failure, out of memory error.

I've seen online that modules should be under 64kb.  The module used to open the button is very small (just opens up UserForm1).

The Userform frm file is 4 KB.
The Userform frx file is 1.24 MB, larger because there are pictures etc. on this form.

The code that the User Form runs.

```
Private Sub ComboBox1_DropButtonClick()

'Determines the controller model based off selection
If ComboBox1.Text = "VHX-6000 + VHX-A60E" Then
    Controller = 6000
Else
    Controller = 950
End If

'Updates textbox1 with current pricing info
TextBox1.Text = Application.VLookup(Controller, Sheet3.Range("A37:C45"), 2, 0)   

End Sub

Private Sub Continue1_Click()

price = 0

'Determines if it should show the camera page based on the controller selection
If Controller = 6000 Then
    CameraForm.Show
Else
    Camera = 6020
    StageForm.Show
End If

End Sub

Private Sub Image6_BeforeDragOver(ByVal Cancel As MSForms.ReturnBoolean, ByVal Data As MSForms.DataObject, ByVal X As Single, ByVal Y As Single, ByVal DragState As MSForms.fmDragState, ByVal Effect As MSForms.ReturnEffect, ByVal Shift As Integer)

End Sub

Private Sub Label2_Click()

End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_Activate()

'Make Sheet 3 activate to avoid that weird error message towards the end
Worksheets("sheet3").Activate

'Sets the dropdown list
ComboBox1.List() = Sheet3.Range("C6:C7").Value

'Clears the quote information if present
Sheet3.Range("M51:O100").ClearContents

Controller = 0

End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_Click()

End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

'Full Screen
With Me
    .Width = Application.Width
    .Height = Application.Height
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Hmm, sounds like you have a recursive call to your form opens in there somewhere.  You're not going to see it before it crashes, because you've tied up the message pump thread.

Comment: Are you getting reasonable values for `Application.Width` and `Application.Height`? If your image is auto-scaling and they're, say, MAX_INT, that could do it.

Comment: @Comintern Tried just removing the part that rescales it and still getting the same error :/

Comment: @RobertHarvey Can you elaborate on this? I'm sorry I'm a bit of a n00b and have been self-teaching myself all of this as I go.  I appreciate your help, just don't fully understand your suggestion.

Comment: Do you know what recursion is?

Comment: @RobertHarvey A formula or section that calls itself, right?

Comment: Yes.  So imagine a form that opens a new instance of itself, which opens a new instance of itself, which ...

Comment: @RobertHarvey hmmm... So everything in the userform code is above.  The button that opens it is literally just

"Sub Button1_Click()
ControllerForm.Show

End Sub"

Does the "click" mean while it's clicked so that it's continually opening my userform?

Comment: Comment-out all that code. Does it fix the problem? Uncomment one procedure at a time, one instruction at a time, testing again between every change, starting with the `Initialize` handler, then the `Activate` hander. Delete the empty stub handler procedures.

Comment: @MathieuGuindon 
Even with everything commented out I still get the error when the button is pressed to open the user form.Could it be something with the button itself to open it.  
`Sub Button 1_Click()`
`ControllerForm.Show`
`End Sub`

Not sure how that simple of a module could be causing a problem!

Comment: `With New ControllerForm`/ `.Show` / `End With` - don't show the default instance. Works? If not, the form module itself might be corrupted. Avoid working with the default instance, especially when adding controls at runtime.

Comment: @MathieuGuindon Same error.  Debugger says it's getting hungup on the first line of `Sub Button1_Click()`

Answer (score 2):

Appreciate this is an old thread but I had a similar problem which has been causing me a headache for a few hours.

I'd been working on dual monitors and set up half a dozen user forms

If I then tried to open some of the user forms on my laptop without any monitors connected I was getting he dramatic, 'catastrophic failure.

I found that the issue was something to do with the screen scale in display settings. My monitors were 100%, with my laptop 125%.

When I changed the laptop to 100%... voila. all working. Bit daft to be honest but thought it worth a mention

Comment: Thanks this solved the issue.. Really weird issue, need to report to microsoft..

Answer (score -1):

## Enigma

Not much to go on:

[image]

To load the form, I have the code for a **Command Button OLE Object** in the **Sheet3 code window**:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
  Load ControllerForm
  ControllerForm.Show
End Sub
```

Notice two differences from your code:

```
Sub Button1_Click()
  ControllerForm.Show
End Sub
```

1. Do you maybe need to use `Load ControllerForm`?
2. There is a difference between those buttons: Commandbutton1 and Button1. Your Button1 is a **msoFormControl** (8), while my button is a **msoOLEControlObject**(12).
   Look [**here**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53094140/excel-vba-error-1004-when-trying-to-delete-buttons-from-a-range-of-cells/53095898#53095898).